# Retrieving exit code from process sent to background in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, exit-code

I have a small bash script which takes a couple of inputs from the terminal, launches a browser and runs a query against a website in the browser. When it is run on a system without a display server, the browser of course fails to launch and I want to detect it in the script. However I am having issues retrieving the exit code from this line - `firefox http://www.411.com/name/$fname'-'$lname &> /dev/null &`. I have seen similar questions here on SO, but am unable to figure out the solution as it applies to me.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo
echo
while [ -z $fname ]; do
   echo -n "First Name: "
   read fname
done
echo
echo -n "Last Name: "
read lname
echo -n "Starting recon on $fname $lname. "
read -p "Press <enter> to continue..."

echo -n "Launching Firefox ...Please wait..."
firefox http://www.411.com/name/$fname'-'$lname &> /dev/null &
status=$?
if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Done"
fi
```

Comment: Remove `&` to get firefox' exit code in `$?`.

Comment: `Launching Firefox ...Please wait...
(process:28086): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified

./example2.sh: line 19: [: -eq: unary operator expected
`

Answer (score 1):

A process that is sent to the background does not return an exit code at that point (it may still be running).

You can't get an exit code from a process that hasn't finished yet. (You can `wait <pid>` to get the return code from a backgrounded process though.)

If you are trying to test for an X server try checking for `$DISPLAY` being set and/or try running some other short-lived X program that you can test for a return code from in the normal fashion.